# Editing a field temporarily in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to display data in multiple forms, but I am pretty new to MSSQL. There is a table with 50 rows with a field like `01Jan2017`, however I need to display this field  like `01/01/2017`. How do I achieve this in MSSQL?.

I have tried small examples of cursors, since this is just an example and I will be editing the data further, I need to iterate trough each row requested and perform multiple editings. What I have achieved so far is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.text2
AS
select TOP (50) * FROM table;
GO
```

This will display 50 rows but I cannot iterate trough its rows or columns. I have also tried with

```
DECLARE cur_mkt CURSOR FOR
select TOP (50) [field] FROM  table

OPEN cur_mkt
FETCH NEXT FROM cur_mkt INTO @A

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        PRINT @A    
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_mkt INTO @A
    END

CLOSE cur_mkt
DEALLOCATE cur_mkt
```

But this will only display one column, and it is not a viable solution because I should be able to work with at least 150 columns.

I have also tried with functions but I have not been able to achieve it. Can you please give me a better directions as to what to try?.

An example of the data in the table would be as follows

```
ID   DATE         PIECE1   PIECE2
1    01Jan2017    ABC      DEF
2    02Jan2017    ABC      DEF
```

Now in the result, data must be displayed

```
ID   DATE         PIECE1   PIECE2  JOIN
1    01/01/2017   ABC      DEF     ABCDEFGHE
2    02/01/2017   ABC      DEF     ABCDEFGHI
```

The "GHE" or "GHI" on the joined row is a string added which can be GHE or GHI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Store your dates as `date` data types (and datetime as `datetime` or `datetime2(0-7)` data types) and format them however you want in your application.

Comment: Are you storing dates as string? Stop doing that and you'll avoid a lot of trouble.

Comment: The forms are windows form or web forms? What is the code to retrieve data from database and display in the form? Which programming language you are using?

Comment: Did you try convert  function in mssql to transform string to date?

Comment: I was working with this on SQL Management studio, using T-SQL. I have not tried to transform string to date because I have not been able to find a way yet.

Comment: Why are you using a cursor here? This should be a single select statement.

Comment: Multiple edits would be made to every row, so I thought of iterating trough every row to edit column by column as needed. This is achievable using cursors right?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select convert(varchar(10),convert(date,'15Jan2017'),101)
```

Returns

```
01/15/2017
```

> **EDIT - Updated for New Infor**

```
Select Top 50  -- << Optional
       A.ID
      ,Date   = convert(varchar(10),convert(date,A.[DATE]),101)
      ,A.PIECE1
      ,A.PIECE2
      ,[JOIN]   = A.PIECE1+A.PIECE2+B.OTHERFIELD  
 From  Table1 A
 Join  Table2 B  on (A.ID=B.ID)
```

**Would Return Something Like this**

```
ID  Date        PIECE1  PIECE2  JOIN
1   01/01/2017  ABC     DEF     ABCDEFxxx
2   01/02/2017  ABC     DEF     ABCDEFyyy
```

Comment: How do I edit this? `Select convert(varchar(10),convert(date,'15Jan2017'),101)`, going by pieces `varchar(10)` Inicial DataType?, `convert(date,'15Jan2017'),101)` how do I change here 15Jan2017 to the field of the table?.

Comment: @CrisAlfie I put 15Jan2017 as a illustration.  just replace the '15Jan2017' with your actual field name

Comment: @CrisAlfie I should add, the first (or inner) convert will transform your string into an date type and the second (or outer) will transform the date into a FORMATTED string

Comment: @CrisAlfie Not clear why you are using a CURSOR here.  Perhaps if you edit your question and supply some sample data and desired results, we  (SO) can offer additional help

Comment: You see, as this date field is just an example, I thought of using cursors first because of similarities with MySQL which I can use better, and also because my idea was to get substrings of the date, but to do that I need to iterate trough each row and each column so I can display every row in the same way. Another example would be concatenate two rows and insert the concatenation into another column.

Comment: @CrisAlfie I'm not getting the visual... again, if you edit your question with sample data and desired results.   As a rule, I avoid CURORS, there is usually a better approach

Comment: @CrisAlfie Just to be clear, not all 150 fields, just a sample will do  :)

Comment: I have edited the question with examples as to things that I want to achieve. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @CrisAlfie two quick questions.  1) Do you want to dynamically concat 150 fields (less id and date) in the JOIN column.   2) what does the Join table look like ?

Comment: At the time I would like to concatenate only 2 fields, and display the concatenation among the added string in a third field. The join table looks like the one I placed in the example. I can display 5 columns for now, but I can add the rest of the columns of the original table if I need to in the future.

Comment: If last added string is variable, but it is an actual string, how is that handled in SQL Server?. I think that is a bit more complicated, let's say that the third string is based on what is actually on PIECE2. If PIECE2 field says Marco, third string to concatenate is Polo, if PIECE2 says Fruit, Third string to concatenate is Vegetables. I guess IF sentences are hard to use in SQL Server?.

Comment: By the way, your answers so far have really helped me, and given me ideas.

Comment: @CrisAlfie Happy it helped, but I have to confess, I'm still a little fuzzy on your goal  :)